# In the Django admin is it possible to separate models into sub-models based on groups?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I think this is easiest to understand as an example:

I have models `Image` and `ImageType`, where and image has exactly one type. The parameters in `ImageType` would regulate image size, thumbnail size, etc., as photo gallery images might display differently from, say, profile pictures.

I want profile images and gallery images to appear as separate models in the Django admin site. One option is to do something like this:

```
class ProfileImage (Image):
    pass

class GalleryImage (Image):
    pass

class ProfileImageAdmin (ImageAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(type='profile')

class GalleryImageAdmin (ImageAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(type='gallery')

admin.site.register(ProfileImage, ProfileImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(GalleryImage, GalleryImageAdmin)
```

But besides having redundant code, that completely defeats the purpose of having a database to organize these in the first place. Another option is to lose my `Image` and `ImageType` models and create separate almost-identical tables for each type (i.e. `ProfileImage` and `GalleryImage`), but that is even worse, since that would require users to have access to the config files, which to my mind nearly defeats the purpose of a CMS.

Is there any way I can do something like this?

```
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin, group_by='type')
```

Alternatively, if this is impossible, does anybody have any suggestions for other ways I could tackle this? (For example, is there a way in python to dynamically create classes based on the database?)

Cheers!
Matt

Comment: No there isn't, but what you could do is add a new url with `get_urls` method on `ModelAdmin` which would point to your custom changelist view on the same `ModelAdmin` class that would set the queryset to be used, and override admins `index.html` in order to change the appearance of the default admin app list page.

Comment: I do not know if it solves your problem, or what things you need to achieve with you `ImageType`-class, but if you do not know it, have a look at the marvellous photologue app (https://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/), which allows to control sizes etc comfortably from the template while the enduser still can specify the sizes and many things more in the admin!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a way. This involves using a [*proxy*](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) model for one (or both) type of images. You can then add separate admins for the two. For e.g.

```
# models.py
class ProfileImage (Image):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class GalleryImage (Image):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

This will avoid creating new tables. You'll still be storing all the data in the table corresponding to the `Image` model. You can then register two different admins for these proxies.

```
# admin.py
class ProfileImageAdmin (ImageAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(type='profile')

class GalleryImageAdmin (ImageAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(type='gallery')

admin.site.register(ProfileImage, ProfileImageAdmin)
admin.site.register(GalleryImage, GalleryImageAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is not quite what I was hoping for, but it is loads better than what I had before, and it looks as if this is as good as it gets. Thanks again!